# get association array specific value

Tags: php

i have array association,an array name is $monitorings. i've tried to see a array value by use function print_r, an output is like this.

```
print_r($monitorings);
 //output
 master_monitoring_collection Object ( [position:protected] => 0 [storage:protected] =>   
 Array ( [0] => master_monitoring Object ( [table:protected] => master_monitoring     
 [values:protected] => Array ( [prvd_name] => Axis [prvd_status] => Y [prvd_lastprob]   
 =>[prvd_prob] => [prvd_traffic_sms] => [update_date] => 2011-11-26 22:54:39 ) ) [1] =>   
 master_monitoring Object ( [table:protected] => master_monitoring [values:protected]=> 
 Array ( [prvd_name] => Esia [prvd_status] => Y [prvd_lastprob] => [prvd_prob] => 
 [prvd_traffic_sms] => [update_date] => 2011-11-26 22:54:07 ) )
```

the problem is i cant get a value when try like this.

```
foreach($monitorings as $monitoring){
   echo $monitoring['prvd_name'];
}
```

please help me..

thanks...

Comment: it's object.`$monitoring = (array) $monitoring`

Comment: What is the variable name? monitoring or monitoringS?

Comment: @RayPaseur: Sorry variable name is $monitorings

Answer (score 0):

Your output will be easier to read if you do two things.  First, echo the preformatting tag before you print it, and second, consider using var_dump() instead of print_r() because var_dump() will give you data type characteristics as well as the visualized contents.

It appears that you have a structure like this.

```
//output
master_monitoring_collection Object ( 
   [position:protected] => 0 
   [storage:protected] => Array ( 
      [0] => master_monitoring Object (  
         [table:protected] => master_monitoring     
         [values:protected] => Array (  
            [prvd_name] => Axis 
            [prvd_status] => Y 
            [prvd_lastprob] => 
            [prvd_prob] => 
            [prvd_traffic_sms] => 
            [update_date] => 2011-11-26 22:54:39 ) 
         ) 
      [1] => master_monitoring Object ( 
         [table:protected] => master_monitoring 
         [values:protected]=> Array ( 
            [prvd_name] => Esia 
            [prvd_status] => Y 
            [prvd_lastprob] => 
            [prvd_prob] => 
            [prvd_traffic_sms] => 
            [update_date] => 2011-11-26 22:54:07 
         ) 
      )
```

You may not be able to get the values because they are protected.  The context of your foreach() instruction matters.  It must be inside the class or an extension of the class to access protected objects.  If it is inside a context that can see the protected properties your iterator might look something like this:

```
foreach ($master_monitoring_collection->storage as $storage)
{
    foreach ($storage as $master_monitoring)
    {
        var_dump($master_monitoring->values['prvd_name']);
    }
}
```

Adjust the variable names as necessary.  Best of luck, ~Ray

Comment: OK, if $monitorings is the name of the master_monitoring_collection object, you can probably just replace the variable name in the outer foreach() loop.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to test out OK.  I changed the properties to "public" so I could avoid writing another class.  The moving parts start on line 80.

http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_casper.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_casper.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

/* STRUCTURE WE ARE TRYING TO CREATE
master_monitoring_collection Object (
   [position:protected] => 0
   [storage:protected] => Array (
      [0] => master_monitoring Object (
         [table:protected] => master_monitoring
         [values:protected] => Array (
            [prvd_name] => Axis
            [prvd_status] => Y
            [prvd_lastprob] =>
            [prvd_prob] =>
            [prvd_traffic_sms] =>
            [update_date] => 2011-11-26 22:54:39 )
         )
      [1] => master_monitoring Object (
         [table:protected] => master_monitoring
         [values:protected]=> Array (
            [prvd_name] => Esia
            [prvd_status] => Y
            [prvd_lastprob] =>
            [prvd_prob] =>
            [prvd_traffic_sms] =>
            [update_date] => 2011-11-26 22:54:07
         )
      )
*/ // END OF STRUCTURE

Class Master_monitoring
{
    public $table, $values;
    public function __construct($values)
    {
        $this->table = 'master_monitoring';
        $this->values = $values;
    }
}

Class Master_monitoring_collection
{
    public $position, $storage;
    public function __construct($array)
    {
        $this->position = 0;
        $this->storage = $array;
    }
}


$a = array
( 'prvd_name'        => 'Axis'
, 'prvd_status'      => 'Y'
, 'prvd_lastprob'    => NULL
, 'prvd_prob'        => NULL
, 'prvd_traffic_sms' => NULL
, 'update_date'      => '2011-11-26 22:54:39'
)
;
$b = array
( 'prvd_name'        => 'Esia'
, 'prvd_status'      => 'Y'
, 'prvd_lastprob'    => NULL
, 'prvd_prob'        => NULL
, 'prvd_traffic_sms' => NULL
, 'update_date'      => '2011-11-26 22:54:07'
)
;

$aobj = new Master_Monitoring($a);
$bobj = new Master_Monitoring($b);
$mobj = array($aobj, $bobj);
$monitors = new Master_monitoring_collection($mobj);

// DOES IT LOOK RIGHT? (YES)
print_r($monitors);

// SHOW HOW TO USE THE ITERATOR
foreach ($monitors->storage as $mmo)
{
    var_dump($mmo->values['prvd_name']);
}
```